# How to call two services from one provider factory?

Tags: angularjs, rest, jakarta-ee, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Hi I am trying to post a discussion and then I want users to comment on it. for this I have exposed two rest services and below is the code where I have defined them. Posting is working fine, but when I am commenting, it is not working. Please let me know where I am going wrong???? if wrong, can u suggest the right way of doing it.

Please note: I am totally new in Angularjs and need it for my app! Thank you very much in advance!

controller.js

```
            'use strict';

            /* Controllers */
            angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
                    controller('MyCtrl1', function($scope, Customers) {
                        $scope.allcustomers = Customers.query();
                    }).
                    controller('MyCtrl2', ['$scope', 'comments', '$location',
                        function($scope, comments, $location) {

                            /* callback for ng-click 'createUser': */
                            $scope.createComment = function() {
                                comments.create($scope.PComment)
                                $scope.allcomments.push($scope.PComment);
                                $scope.PComment = "";
                                $location.path('/view2');

                                $scope.allcomments = PComment.query();

                            };
                        }

                    ]).
                    controller('MyCtrl3', ['$scope', 'postmain', '$location',
                        function($scope, postmain, $location) {

                            /* callback for ng-click 'createUser': */
                            $scope.createPost = function() {
                                postmain.create($scope.PPostMain)
                                $scope.allposts.push($scope.PPostMain);
                                $scope.PPostMain = "";
                                $location.path('/view2');
                            }

                            $scope.allposts = postmain.query();
                        }]);
```

services.js

```
            'use strict';

            /* Services */
            angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource'], function($provide) {
                $provide.factory('postmain', function($resource) {
                    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/pingleMe/webresources/postmain', {}, {
                        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
                        create: {method: 'POST'} 
                    });
                });

                $provide.factory('comments', function($resource) {
                    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/pingleMe/webresources/comments', {}, {
                        query: {
                            method: 'GET',
                            isArray: true
                        },
                        create: {method: 'POST'}
                    });
                });

            //
            //    $provide.factory('Comments', function($resource) {
            //        return $resource('http://localhost:8080/CustomerBack/webresources/comments', {}, {
            //            query: {
            //                method: 'GET',
            //                isArray: true
            //            },
            //            create: {method: 'POST'}
            //        });
            //    });
            });
```

app.js

```
            'use strict';


            // Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
            angular.module('myApp', [
              'ngRoute',
              'myApp.filters',
              'myApp.services',
              'myApp.directives',
              'myApp.controllers'
            ]).
            config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
              $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
              $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
              $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl3'});

              $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
            }]);
```

partila2.html

```
            <div class="container">
                <h1>What's on your mind?</h1>

                <form novalidate="novalidate" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">                     
                            <textarea ng-model="PPostMain.postText" placeholder="whats in your mind" style='width:550px'></textarea>
                            <button ng-click='createPost()' class="btn btn-warning">Post</button>

                            <h4>Trending Posts</h4>

                            <p ng-repeat="post in allposts"> 
                                {{ post.postText}} <br>

                                <label ng-repeat="comnt in allcomments">{{comnt}}</label>
                                <textarea ng-model="PComment.commentText" placeholder="write comment" style='width:350px'></textarea>
                                <button ng-click='createComment()' class="btn btn-success">Comment</button>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

index.html

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
            <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <title>Pingle</title>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/lib/angular/i18n/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
              <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
              </ul>

              <div ng-view></div>

              <!-- In production use:
              <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
              -->
              <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
              <script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
              <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
              <script src="js/app.js"></script>
              <script src="js/services.js"></script>
              <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
              <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
              <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
              <script src="app/lib/angular/i18n/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to angularjs also. But shouldn't you have a comment per row?

You now have only one Pcomment on the scope. Does the last row determine the contents of pcomment?

Comment: Right now, just trying to push comment data into db, I have to make some changes related to commenting like each row can have nultiple comments. But first is not working so cant proceed!

Comment: I would suggest to put the comment value in comnt like comnt.newcomment. That way each row has it's own field. You can then give the row to the submit function.createComment(comnt)